# Check PHP exec / system is finish and call a function

Tags: php, function, system, exec

```
system("convert -colorspace RGB -density 134.5 -quality 100 ".$result_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$pdf." -channel rgba -alpha on PNG32:".$gen_folder_path.'PNG'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$baseName.".png",$genPopTxtResult);

checkSuccess($genPopTxtResult,'popTxt',$baseName.'.png');
```

The above code is execute the command using PHP and using the output result for checking .
However, php will not trigger the checkSuccess after the system finish its execution. Instead, it will just trigger after the system is started, So the result will never success (the system function is not finish so not true).

How to fix the problem so that checkSuccess is call only after system is finish? thanks.

Comment: You have something other going on, `system()` will return when the command it is executing finishes ...

Comment: Thanks,  how can I call a function when system is finish?

Comment: Your script will continue to execute once the system() finishes. So you code should work, you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: That means the $genPopTxtResult return 0 is due to the error in the command in system function?\